# 2 virtual domains: one on port 80 one on port 8080, how?

Tags: apache-2.2, domain, bind, virtualization, proxypass

I've been struggling with this, basically what I want is this:

A virtual domain to run on the 80
another virtual domain to run FROM 80 TO 8080

what I've done so far is trying different combinations with apache, but all i got is having all the virtual domains pointing to port 80
this is my conf:

```
<VirtualHost domain1.com:80>
DocumentRoot /var/www/domain1
<Directory "/var/www/domain1">
allow from all
Options +Indexes
</Directory>
ServerName domain1.com
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost server.domain2.com:80>
DocumentRoot /var/www
<Directory "/var/www">
allow from all
Options +Indexes
</Directory>

    ServerName server.domain2.com
    ServerAlias www.server.domain2.com
    ProxyPass / http://server.domain2.com:8080/

       </VirtualHost>
```

suggestions? :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do domain1.com / server.domain2.com resolve on different addresses? If not you're aiming for NameVirtualHost Configuration:

```
NameVirtualHost *:80
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName domain1.com
    ...
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName server.domain2.com
    ...        
    ProxyPass / http://server.domain2.com:8080/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://server.domain2.com:8080/
    ...
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: thanks! adding NameVirtualHost *:80
Listen 80 did the trick